# Disable completion of arithmetic expressions in ZSH

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I type:

```
echo "$((1 + 2))"
```

And then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, ZSH will transform what I typed into:

```
echo 3
```

How can I disable this behavior? I don't want ZSH to evaluate the arithmetic expression when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I want expansion for everything except arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Why don't you just press space instead of tab? What exactly do you expect tab to do in that situation, if not do expansion?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific setting for what you want, but this works:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
bindkey '^I' complete-word
zstyle -e ':completion:*' completer '
  if [[ $PREFIX$SUFFIX == \$\(\(*\)\) ]]; then 
    reply=( _complete _ignored )
  else 
    reply=( _expand _complete _ignored )
  fi'
```

This simply tells the completion system that when the current shell word (the one that the cursor is on) is of the form `$((…))`, then don't use the `_expand` completer.